# If the sum of the digits of n is equal to the sum of the digits of 5n, then prove that 9|n.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So far I have: If the sum of the digits of $n$ is $k$, then $n = 9m + k$, where $m$ element of an integer (not sure why). Now consider $5n-n$.

Help?

Comment: Note that $10\equiv 1 \mod 9$, so that $10^r\equiv 1 \mod 9$ whence $\sum a_r10^r\equiv \sum a_r \mod 9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $n=9i + k$ and $5n = 9j+ k$. So $4n = 9(j-i)$ is divisible by $9$. But since $\gcd(4,9)=1$, we must have that $n$ is divisible by $9$.

Comment: but why is n = 9i + k and 5n = 9j + k. I can't even come up with an example where the sum of all digits is the same number as the sum of all digits times 5 >_>

Comment: $9$ and $45$ is one example. As for why any number minus the sum of its digits is divisible by $9$, didn't you just state that as though you knew it as a fact in the question?

Comment: I'm definitely not understanding. how is 9 = 45. n != 5n, where 9 != 45

Comment: No, the sum of digits in $45$ is $4+5=9$, which is the same as the sum of digits in $9$. So with $n=9$, you have an example of a number with the property mentioned, and it just so happens that $9$ does divide this $n$, just as it should according to the theorem we wish to prove.

Comment: Another example: $n=144$, sum of digits is $1+4+4= 9$. Sum of digits in $5n$ is $7+2+0=9$, so they have the same sum of digits. The theorem then says that $n$ should be divisible by $9$, and it is: $144=9\cdot16$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** start to prove that if $S(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$, then
$
n - S(n)
$ is a multiple of 9.